# Getting an HTML input range value to a NEW objects argument

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I want to get a an HTML input range sliders value to the **sliderVal** argument slot of the snareDrum variable dynamically.

```
document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('change', function() {
var sliderVal = document.getElementById("slider").value;

// Event handler code....I tried a bunch of different things


}); 


// Don't know how to get it to the sliderVal  argument.

var snareDrum = new audioApiKey("snareDrum","snare.mp3",false, sliderVal); 









// Abstracted Web Audio playback Block


var context = new webkitAudioContext();
 function audioApiKey(domNode,fileDirectory,loopOnOff,playBackSpeed) {
    this.domNode = domNode;
    this.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;
    this.playBackSpeed = playBackSpeed;
    var bufferFunctionName = bufferFunctionName;
    var incomingBuffer;
    var savedBuffer;
    var xhr;

       bufferFunctionName = function () {          
       var source = context.createBufferSource();
       source.buffer = savedBuffer;
       source.loop = loopOnOff;
       source.playbackRate.value = playBackSpeed;
       source.connect(context.destination);
       source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately
       };
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get',fileDirectory, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function () {
    context.decodeAudioData(xhr.response,
       function(incomingBuffer) {
       savedBuffer = incomingBuffer;
       var note = document.getElementById(domNode);
       note.addEventListener("click", bufferFunctionName , false);
         }
      );
   };
 xhr.send();
 };
```

Below is working code, but it is done by modifying **audioApiKey** and **bufferFunctionName**

```
var snareDrumPitchSlider = document.getElementById("snareDrumPitchSlider");
var snareDrum = new audioApiKey("snareDrum","snare.mp3",false,"snareDrumPitchSlider");


// Abstracted Web Audio playback Block

var context = new webkitAudioContext();

 function audioApiKey(domNode,fileDirectory,loopOnOff,pitchSlider) {
    this.domNode = domNode;
    this.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;
    this.pitchSlider = pitchSlider;
    var bufferFunctionName = bufferFunctionName;
    var incomingBuffer;
    var savedBuffer;
    var xhr;

       bufferFunctionName = function () {          
       var source = context.createBufferSource();
       source.buffer = savedBuffer;
       source.loop = loopOnOff;
       var speed = document.getElementById(pitchSlider).value; // Added
       source.playbackRate.value = speed;
       source.connect(context.destination);
       source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately

       };

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get',fileDirectory, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function () {
    context.decodeAudioData(xhr.response,
       function(incomingBuffer) {
       savedBuffer = incomingBuffer;
       var note = document.getElementById(domNode);
       note.addEventListener("click", bufferFunctionName , false);



         }

      );
   };
 xhr.send();
 };
```

Comment: You are confusing jQuery with javascript. You can only execute jQuery methods on jQuery objects.

Comment: Which is why many times people have variables that are jquery objects start with `$`, that is `var $obj = $()` so that you don't forget what is a jQuery object and what isn't

Answer (score 2):

It's a scope issue, by the looks of it. Try moving the declaration of sliderVal outside the listener, like so:

```
var sliderVal; //feel free to set it to a default
document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('change', function() {
    sliderVal = document.getElementById("slider").value;
    // Event handler code....
}); 


// sliderVal should now be accessible
var snareDrum = new audioApiKey("snareDrum","snare.mp3",false, sliderVal);
```

Comment: If that is supposed to work out the box it doesn't. Placing console.log(sliderVal) after the event handler doesn't output a stream of slider values when the input range slider is moved.

Comment: It's def a scope issue. I'm just hoping I don't have to dig into the abstracted block to remedy it.

Comment: If you put the console.log within the listener it should log each time the value is changed. No code outside the handler will be run when the value changes, unless you explicitly do a function call from within the handler. By the look of your code I'm assuming you want the sliderVal to update each time the slider is moved, and then that value is used whenever a new snare sound is played, correct? If so, this code ought to do the trick.

Comment: You are correct, I simply want the snare to reflect the updated slider value when played which should be the playback speed. I modified the code above and added a version that works but I did it by modifying the abstracted block ( which I didn't want to do). No matter what I do I wasn't able to get it to work the other way but I "feel" like it should be able to. I'm really trying to edge my coding away from vanilla constructors and pass things around differently so I can learn but I keep getting pulled back into habit.

Comment: Aha, now I see what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to pass sliderVal by reference. Primitive values are passed by value, though, so that's why the value doesn't update as you expect. Check this link which explains what happens when you pass differnet parameters to functions. http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: I understand the general concept in this article and will read it in it's entirety. I thought there might be a way to modify the sliderVal within the eventListener and then somehow spit it out after it was affected and plop it in the argument of the snareDrum.

Comment: You could, if you use my example above where the variable is defined outside the handler, and then change "source.playbackRate.value = playBackSpeed" to "source.playbackRate.value = sliderVal" in the bufferFunctionName function. That way the function checks the value of sliderValue each time it's run.

Comment: Technically you're correct but the problem with that is if I create multiple sounds (kick,snare,hat) the pitch change will affect them all instead of each having their own independent pitch setting. I should have mentioned that this was part of what I was looking for.